# Ayuda al instalar Vue

Tags: windows, vue.js

estoy instalando Vue y crear un proyecto por lo que me fui a la documentación
https://cli.vuejs.org/

Instalo Vue con:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Pero al momento de hacer el segundo comando:
vue create my-project

Me sale que

> "vue" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna solución?

Comment: simplemente abre una nueva consola, paraque te reconozca el comando

Comment: Ya hice eso, una nueva consola y aun no me reconoce el comando vue

Comment: Fijate que el npm este en una ruta del path. si no, no sabe donde tiene vue

Comment: Te pido por favor que mires el [tour], esta no es tu primera pregunta y ninguna tiene una respuesta aceptada. Y se pide que los errores esten como texto, porque las imagenes son dificiles de ver.

Comment: y de paso, mira [ask]

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asegurate que la ruta:

```
C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

se encuentre dentro de la variable de entorno Path.

El [proceso](https://andrezgz.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/agregar-ruta-a-la-variable-path-en-windows/) para agregar la ruta en Windows :

1. Acceder a Sistema:

   - Panel de Control > Sistema
   - Click derecho en el icono Mi PC > Propiedades
2. Elegir de las opciones a la izquierda “Configuración avanzada del sistema”
3. Pulsar el botón “Variables de entorno…”, estando en la pestañan Opciones avanzadas
4. En el listado de Variables del sistema seleccionar la variable Path y presionar “Editar…”
5. Agregar al final de la lista, la ruta hacia la aplicación deseada
6. Presionar Aceptar en las 2 pantallas

En mi caso se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]